# How to fix background image overlap in carousel when using a mousemove effect

Tags: javascript, html, css, mousemove, flickity

I am trying to use Flickity carousel with a mousemove effect. There are 3 background images in the carousel. Everything works except when the carousel transitions from the 3rd image to the 1st, the 3rd image shows for a second (on top of the first image) then disappears. If it would be helpful to see that, here it is: http://www.tishomingofunhere.org/NEW/

I've tried using z-index various ways, but that just changes where the problem occurs. Any help would be much appreciated.

Here is relevant code:
HTML

CSS

```
.carousel-cell {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    height: 512px;
}
#carousel-cell-image1, #carousel-cell-image2, #carousel-cell-image3{
    width: 120%;
    left:-2%;
    top:-2%;
    height: 512px;
    position: absolute;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    transform: scale(1.1);
}
#carousel-cell-image1 {
     background-image: url(../images/photos/natchez-trace-parkway1-CROPPED.jpg);
   }
#carousel-cell-image2 {
    background-image: url(../images/photos/waterskiing.jpg);
}
#carousel-cell-image3 {
    background-image: url(../images/photos/retire.jpg);

}

JS

var lFollowX = 0,
    lFollowY = 0,
    x = 0,
    y = 0,
    friction = 1 / 30;

function moveBackground() {
  x += (lFollowX - x) * friction;
  y += (lFollowY - y) * friction;

  translate = 'translate(' + x + 'px, ' + y + 'px) scale(1.1)';

  $('.carousel-cell').css({
    '-webit-transform': translate,
    '-moz-transform': translate,
    'transform': translate
  });

  window.requestAnimationFrame(moveBackground);
}

$(window).on('mousemove click', function(e) {

  var lMouseX = Math.max(-100, Math.min(100, $(window).width() / 2 - e.clientX));
  var lMouseY = Math.max(-100, Math.min(100, $(window).height() / 2 - e.clientY));
  lFollowX = (5 * lMouseX) / 100; // 100 : 12 = lMouxeX : lFollow
  lFollowY = (5 * lMouseY) / 100;

});

moveBackground();
```

Comment: I've tried the suggestions below. Anyone else have any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#carousel-cell-image1, #carousel-cell-image2, #carousel-cell-image3{
    width: 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: Meghna, unfortunately that didn't work. :(  I updated the link above so you can see the results.

Comment: I tried with width: 100%; then image is not overlapping. @Newsong80

Comment: Hm, still overlapping for me. What could be different between you and I?

Comment: I now know this, it doesn't have anything to do with mousemove effect. I even took that out and it still overlaps. It must be the Flickity carousel.

Comment: Use slick slider instead of this if you can change the slider. @Newsong80

Answer (score 0):

Replace Your Code With It.

```
#carousel-cell-image1, #carousel-cell-image2, #carousel-cell-image3{
width: 100%;
left:-2%;
top:-2%;
height: 512px;
position: absolute;
background-size: cover;
background-position: center;
transform: scale(1.1);
}
```

Comment: Akash, results didn't change.